# CALayer draw outside of rect

Tags: ios

I'm using this code to add a layer to a custom UIView and it works like a charm:

```
 CGRect newrect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    CALayer* heartBackground = [CALayer layer];
    heartBackground.contents = (__bridge id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"5HeartsGray"].CGImage);
    heartBackground.frame = newrect;
    [self.layer addSublayer:heartBackground];
```

But when I tried to use it in draw method using Quartz using a new Rect(like this)

```
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGRect ratingRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 150, 20);

    CALayer* heartBackground = [CALayer layer];
    heartBackground.contents = (__bridge id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"5HeartsGray"].CGImage);
    heartBackground.frame = ratingRect;
    [heartBackground renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

It renders in the beginning of the frame and not inside of ratingRect.

If I call `[heartBackground setNeedsDisplay]` it disappear. The same thing with `heartBackground.masksToBounds = YES`

What I'm doing wrong. Do I need To switch to CGLayer because I'm using CoreGraphics?

This is the output when working with CoreGraphics (as you see the hearts starts at coordinates x=0, y=0 and normally it starts at x=250, y=100):
[image]

Comment: You most likely want `heartBackground.masksToBounds = NO`

Comment: @MNIFAKRAM please share screen shot of Your output..

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have updated the thread with the output.

Comment: @MNIFAKRAM still you question not clear. you want heart in centre location ?

Comment: @AshokLondhe yes. I'm not able to move them to any location, tried multiple value on ratingRect and no hope.

Comment: @MNIFAKRAM i will try. wait.

Comment: In DrawRect: method we can draw image using drawInRect: "- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    CGRect ratingRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 150, 20); UIImage * heartBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5HeartsGray.png"];
    [heartBackground drawInRect:ratingRect];
}"

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 Yes I know that but I need to use layers because I'm gonna fill it with another layer using sublayer and CALayer.mask.

Comment: @MNIFAKRAM is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to create and draw a `CALayer` inside draw function of a `UIView`. `CALayer` is an independently drawable unit and it draws itself on its parentLayer's context by default. Which means if you really want to use separate CALayers try adding as many subLayers to self.layer (inside a `UIView`) as you want, set their frames and they'll get drawn when their container view shows up. Regarding your problem, here's what you can try.

**Option 1:** Take this code

```
CGRect ratingRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 150, 20);
CALayer* heartBackground = [CALayer layer];
heartBackground.contents = (__bridge id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"5HeartsGray"].CGImage);
heartBackground.frame = ratingRect;
[self.layer addSubLayer:heartBackground];
```

Out of the `drawRect:` method and write it in `initWithFrame:` and in drawRect simply do `[heartBackground renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext];`

**Option 2:** Draw your hearts without a CALayer.

```
CGRect ratingRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 150, 20);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"5HeartsGray"] drawInRect:ratingRect];
```